# Atomically copy a bit (or bits) into an integer

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, atomic, bit

I have some code that copies masked bits into an integer by first clearing them in the target int then ORing them into the int.

Like this:

```
bitsToSet = 6
targetInt &= ~(1 << bitsToSet)
targetInt |= desiredBitValue << bitsToSet
```

The problem is that it now needs to be thread safe, and I need to make the operation atomic. I think that using std:atomic<int> would only make each sub-operation atomic but not the operation as a whole.

How can I make the whole operation (including both the &= and the |= operations) atomic?

For example, it would solve the problem for me if I had a function (or better, a macro) like `SetBits(TARGET, MASK, VALUE)` that would atomically set the MASKed bits in TARGET to VALUE. The MASK and VALUE can already be left-shifted.

My current, non-atomic code is

```
#define SetBits(TARGET, MASK, VALUE) {(TARGET) &= ~((uint64_t)MASK); (TARGET)|=((uint64_t)VALUE);}
```

Comment: CAS (compare and swap) is a very general solution. If your platform has atomic or and and, you could first test if the desiredBitValue is 1 or 0, then you only need or (for 1) or and (for 0) and can do that one atomically.

Comment: There are many cases where I have to cover multiple bits at once. Thanks for the comment! I'll update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a compare-exchange loop:

```
void SetBitsAtomic(std::atomic<int>& target, int mask, int value) {
    int original_value = target.load();
    int new_value = original_value;
    SetBits(new_value, mask, value);
    while (!target.compare_exchange_weak(original_value, new_value)) {
        // Another thread may have changed target between when we read
        // it and when we tried to write to it, so try again with the
        // updated value
        new_value = original_value;
        SetBits(new_value, mask, value);
    }
}
```

This reads the original value of `target`, does the masking operations, and then writes the modified value back to `target` only if no other thread has modified it since it was read.  If another thread has modified `target` then its updated value gets written into `original_value` and it keeps trying until it manages to update `target` before anyone else.

Note that I've used (default) full sequential consistency here for the `load` and `compare_exchange_weak` operations.  You may not need full sequential consistency, but I have no way of knowing exactly what you need without more info on what you're using this for.

---

Alternatively, you could just use a mutex:

```
std::mutex mtx;

void SetBitsAtomic(int& target, int mask, int value) {
    std::lock_guard lock{mtx};
    SetBits(target, mask, value);
}
```

This *may* be less performant than the lock-free `compare_exchange_weak` version, but again it really depends what it's being used for.  It's certainly simpler and easier to reason about, which may be more important than raw performance in your situation.

Comment: There can be thousands of these flags and dozens of references and would require recursive mutex so I am trying to avoid mutexes. 
I am trying to understand the compare_exchange_weak() solution. Should `new_value = original value` be `new_value = target.load()`?

Comment: Oh I see, you did explain that it updates original_value. I'll read about full sequential consistency. Lastly, given the interplay between the condition and body of the while-loop, (and the fact that this technique is new to me), is there any reason this could not be a do-while loop to save the extra 2 lines initializing new_value?

Comment: @BruceDLong A do-while would be perfectly fine.  As for learning about sequential consistency, [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQFzMfHIxng) from CppCon 2017 has some good info on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

Copying a bit can be done atomically without a [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap), but at the expense of a conditional code. Indeed, setting a bit can be done with an atomic *or* and clearing a bit can be done with an atomic *and*. The trick is to combine them together:

```cpp
bitToSet = 7;

// Assume targetInt is of type std::atomic<int>
if(desiredBitValue)
    targetInt.fetch_or(1 << bitToSet);
else
    targetInt.fetch_and(~(1 << bitToSet));
```

For multiple bits, the only portable way to do that in C++ so far is to use a `compare_exchange_weak` operation on `targetInt` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::mutex`. Your code should look like this:

```
mutex m;

void SetBitsAtomic()
{
    m.lock();
    bitToSet = 7;
    targetInt &= ~(1 << bitToSet);
    targetInt |= desiredBitValue << bitToSet;
    m.unlock();
}
```

Comment: This won't work as the mutex is local to this code -- another thread doing the same will have a completely independent mutex.  You need to make the mutex global and associate it with targetInt so that all threads will use the same mutex for modifying this variable.

Comment: Yes the mutex must be global, need to edit it.

Comment: But now it should worck exactly the way.